# Proof-verification: every prime ideal is radical

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Using the following definition of radical ideal:

> $I$ is radical if and only if $I = \{r \in R \mid \exists n>0: r^n \in I  \}$

I have found a direct proof by induction ([on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034288/prove-every-prime-ideal-of-a-ring-is-a-radical-ideal) or [here](http://www-home.math.uwo.ca/%7Esrankin/courses/4123/2011/majed_presentation.pdf), [here](http://planetmath.org/everyprimeidealisradical)) and a direct proof using sub-ideals (see [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/in-a-commutative-ring-prime-ideals-are-radical/) or [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/commalg-2013/chapter-2.pdf)) of this result. Obviously the result is trivial if one uses the (equivalent) definition of radical ideal as the intersection of all prime ideals containing the ideal.

**Question:** However, the easiest way to prove this result seems to be by contraposition. However, I have not seen anyone use this proof (it admittedly is similar to, but, I think, still simpler than, the induction proof), so I wanted to double-check that it is correct.

> The desired result is equivalent to $I$ is not radical $\implies$ $I$ is not prime. Let $I$ not be radical. Then there exists a $P \in R$ such that $P \not\in I$ but $P^m \in I$ for some $m \ge 2$.
>
> Let $m_0$ be the smallest integer such that $P^{m_0} \in I$ (which exists by the well-ordering principle).
>
> Thus since $(P)(P^{m_0 - 1}) =P^{m_0}\in I$, but $P \not\in I$ and $P^{m_0 -1}\not\in I$, $I$ is not prime. $\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. But the induction proof is just as simple (and direct proofs are IMHO a little nicer) :)